# How to use udf and class in pyspark withcolumn

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm use pyspark
But, I don't know How to use my define class.

```
class TEST:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content

    def my_function(self):
        return self.content + "text"

df.withColumn("test", TEST(content=col("TEST")))
```

But, <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'> Column<b'Con'>

How do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call directly your custom functions with `.withColumn(..)`, you need to use UserDefinedFunctions (UDF)

`.withColumn` expects the second argument to be a Column Expression. Hence, you can use your custom functions using below approaches by converting those into UDF and call inside `.withColumn` :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

udf_func = udf(lambda content : content + "text", StringType())

df_result= df.withColumn("test",udf_func(content))
df_result.show()
```

Or if you would like to have a class, you can do something similar:

```
class TEST:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content

    def my_function(self):
        return self.content + "text"

udf_func = udf(lambda content: TEST(content).myfunction(), StringType())
df_result= df.withColumn("test",udf_func(content))
```